# Dynamic Json deserialization

Tags: c#, dynamic

[Deserialize JSON into C# dynamic object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object)

Following above question, I copy the dynamicJsonDeserilization and trying to use that in my application.

then I try to access the object as

```
var Data = json.deserilization(jsonstring);
```

Now, my string is

{"0":{"Name":"C:\\","Type":"Partition","Path":"C:\\"},"1":{"Name":"D:\\","Type":"Partition","Path":"D:\\"},"2":{"Name":"E:\\","Type":"Partition","Path":"E:\\"}}

i.e. I just have an Array on my server which I convert to JSON string and send.

As per code from best answer I should be able to access it as `Data.0` but it give "End of Expression expected", Also `Data[0]` is giving same error. I am not sure how can I use it ? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting `Data` by setting a breakpoint at the appropriate position and then holding the mouse pointer over `Data`? This gives you good insight into the object structure of `Data`.

Comment: I did, it show me something this {Name:"ABC",Type:"10"},Name:"Test","Age":"10"}} which looks little bad to me too.

Comment: Go to http://jsonlint.com/ and feed it your string to verify if it's valid JSON

Comment: I don't think so - this doesn't match at all the JSON string you're showing.

Comment: I did that already and JSON is valid ...

Comment: Okay I change it to original generated JSON String as I see it in browser window. I am fetching remote server Drive Information and hence we get drive name in our string. I should have posted that earlier.

Answer (score 0):

> Now, my string is
>
> {"0":{"Name":"C:\","Type":"Partition","Path":"C:\"},"1":{"Name":"D:\","Type":"Partition","Path":"D:\"},"2":{"Name":"E:\","Type":"Partition","Path":"E:\"}}

Your string is indeed not valid JSON due to escaped quotes.

Those `C:\` are breaking the parser. You should generate it like this, sending *three* backslahes:

> {"0":{"Name":"C:\\\","Type":"Partition","Path":"C:\\\"} ...

Comment: well I have escape slashes already, but I fix them in my question I didn't know the formatting on stackoverflow before. Sorry.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. The fixed string contains **three** backslashes. I'll try and work around the formatting now.